# workaround for browser font sizing (using rem)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I've been using rem sizing instead of px for all styling and have noticed if the user changes their browser font size to small, it will then remove the borders.

Here's a link as reference, just change your browser text settings from medium to small, the first div is with rem second is with px.

http://jsbin.com/pozex/1/edit

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: .1rem is based on the font size and once the font size is small enough to make .1rem less than a single pixel, its too small to be seen.

Comment: change your border size to .2rem and it reappears or define the div height/width. It seems as though .1rem for the border will be too small and thus hidden when the font shrinks the size of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should not use rem for border size in my opinion (except for some rare cases maybe). Specially if you want to have a hair-line border then use 1px. There is nothing wrong with using pixels where they actually make sense.

We have used rem's with pixel fallback in large scale web projects but never used rem for the border sizes (but we have only used hair-line borders most of the cases). In my opinion units relative to font (rem, em, ch) should be used for content relevant elements such as font-sizes and negative space between content elements using padding / margin.

Sometimes even rem's are not the nicest solution. They are great because they are predictable in comparison to em's but you also loose a lot of dynamics. Recently we were following an [idea by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/) to set a font-size in rem on component level (article, product teaser etc.) and then use em on sub-elements of the component. This gives you the flexibility to change the rem font-size on component level to scale the whole component content.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use box-shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/KsW2s/.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

div:first-of-type {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem red;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1.6rem;
}

div:last-of-type {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 16px;
}
```